# ASP.NET DataContext GridView Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging, datacontext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The data source does not support server-side data paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661292/the-data-source-does-not-support-server-side-data-paging)

I have a GridView that is databound to returned results using a LINQ Query. I have enabled paging on the gridview as there are about 300 records returned.

I created a search function that generates general SQL Queries and returns a result. However I get the following error when it is executed.

```
The data source does not support server-side data paging.
```

Here is my code that performs the SQL Search.

```
    IEnumerable<equipment> result = db.ExecuteQuery<equipment>(SQLQuery);
    equipmentGrid.DataSource = result;
    equipmentGrid.DataBind();
```

This is the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="equipmentGrid" OnPageIndexChanging="equipmentGrid_PageIndexChanging" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="details.aspx?EQCN=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EQCN") %>">Details</a> | 
                    <a href="edit.aspx?EQCN=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EQCN") %>">Edit</a> | 
                    <a href="delete.aspx?EQCN=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EQCN") %>">Delete</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And the OnPageIndexChanging function

```
protected void equipmentGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    equipmentGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    equipmentGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks so mucH!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Gridview's AllowPaging property to true:

```
<asp:GridView ID="equipmentGrid" OnPageIndexChanging="equipmentGrid_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AllowPaging="true">
```

And you may need to call ToList() on your LINQ query. You could also setup a LINQ datasource in the aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ...

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    // Add here your method for DataBinding
     BindGridControl();

    gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridView.DataBind();
 }
```

Without the databinding method you won't get the paged result.