# The data source does not support server-side data paging. 

Tags: asp.net

I have created one form.In that form,after clicking on button result shown in grid.In cs file ,I am writing code for executing query and store result in dataset and bind.It is working fine.In grid,I mention flase to autogenerated columns,declare new columns and allowpaging and given page size.when I selecting perticular user,that person's data seen in gridview.If record not available,showing no record available.Suppose When selecting user called nadini, record seen in grid.When I am selecting other user,that person's data is not available,displaying that no record available.But grid (previously appear for nandini) is not disappear.So I tried to write like this gridview.datasource ="";gridview.DataBind(); at starting of button click event.I am getting error that The data source does not support server-side data paging.

Comment: Add your Databind on your datagrid paging event on code behind

Comment: you can use sqldatasource or object datasource and bind it to your datagrid.

Comment: I have solved my problem by doing like this,in button click event
before writing these 2 statement(gridview.Datasource =""; gridview.DataBind()),wrote allowpaging = flase and after writing the above 2 statement again wrote allowpaging = true;.It is working properly.

Comment: what i know is `list` for example doesn't support paging as a datasource . u can use datatable ,or sqldatasource

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that my problem was passing an `IEnumerable<T>` as the `GridView3.DataSource`. I solved it by changing to an `IList<T>` The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661292/the-data-source-does-not-support-server-side-data-paging) is kinda the same.