# Unable to bind list to gridview after sorted using linq ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, linq, sorting, gridview

I am sorting a list of object and binding the sorted list to a gridview that supports paging.
I tried:

```
var selectedNew = selected.AsQueryable<Customer>().OrderBy(sortExpression);
selectedNew.ToList<Customer>();
gdvEmployees.DataSource = selectedNew;
gdvEmployees.DataBind();
```

I am getting the following error:

> The data source does not support server-side data paging

What is causing the above error to be thrown?

Comment: can you provide stack trace? and more code?

Comment: possibly duplicate [the-data-source-does-not-support-server-side-data-paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661292/the-data-source-does-not-support-server-side-data-paging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToList produces an output, you cannot use it by itself. try this:

```
var selectedNew = selected.AsQueryable<Customer>().OrderBy(sortExpression);
var selectedNewList = selectedNew.ToList<Customer>();
gdvEmployees.DataSource = selectedNewList;
gdvEmployees.DataBind();
```